# how to send complex object as parameter to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Html Table which displays data and is having delete and update functionality as below,

```
function DesignBTable(data) {
    $("#ExpTableBody tr").remove();
    var rowIndex = 0;
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        var fromDt = moment(value.from_date).format("MMM/YYYY");
        var toDt = moment(value.to_date).format("MMM/YYYY");

        $("#ExpTableBody").append("<tr>" +
            "<td>" + value.org_name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + fromDt + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + toDt + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + value.designation + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + value.location + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + value.is_relevant + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + '<input type="button" value = "X" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(\'' + value.exp_id + '\',\'' + value.from_date + '\')">' + '  ' +
             '<input type="button" value = "E" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick="Javacsript:editRow(\'' + value + '\')">' + "</td>" +

            "</tr>");
        //alert(moment(value.from_date).format("MM/YYYY"));
        rowIndex++;
    });
};
```

The value object contains various fields.
On the Click event of the delete button I send value.exp_id and value.from_date as parameter to deleteRow function.

I want to add Edit functionality where if I click on the edit button it should send the value as object so that I can access all the fields in it.

When I try to send value as parameter to the JS function it errors out as undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a string for code that uses the object, you would need to create a string representation of the object:

```
... onClick="editRow(' + JSON.stringify(value) + ')" ...
```

(Note: The [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is not supported in some older browsers.)

If you create elements directly instead of creating a string that you create elements from, you can bind the event directly and use the object without creating a string representation of it:

```
$("#ExpTableBody").append(
  $("<tr>").append([
    $("<td>").text(value.org_name),
    $("<td>").text(fromDt),
    $("<td>").text(toDt),
    $("<td>").text(value.designation),
    $("<td>").text(value.location),
    $("<td>").text(value.is_relevant),
    $("<td>").append([
      $("<input>", { type: "button", value: "X", className: "btn btn-danger btn-sm" }).click(function(){
        deleteRow(value.exp_id, value.from_date)
      }),
      $("<input>", { type: "button", value: "E", className: "btn btn-info btn-sm" }).click(function(){
        editRow(value);
      })
    ])
  ])
);
```

As a side effect, by using the `text` method to put the values in the cells, it's protected agains script injection. If you actually have HTML code that you want to put in a cell, you would use the `html` method instead. That naturally means that you should encode it properly when you create that HTML code to protect against script injection.

---

Side note: The `javascript:` pseudo protocol is only used when you put code in an URL, i.e. a `href` attribute. If you use it anywhere else it becomes a label instead. This is not harmful, but useless and confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your brief explanation. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem of 'value' accessibility is it's defined only inside the function not outside.

I see you use JQuery, so you can use [JQuery.data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to make a link between an html object and a custom value. In your case you can add the value directly to the button at the end of the row.